# ¿Como puedo automatizar un captcha?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

estoy intentando automatizar un registro y me parece un captcha y no se como puedo automatizarlo. Este es mi codigo de PO:

```
public void inicio(String name, String number)   {
        Squery.newVentana(driver);
        assertPage();
        Screenshooter.takeScreenshot("Capturas\\loginNew\\LOGIN", driver);
        inputRegistro.click();
        inputRegistro.sendKeys(name);
        btnRegistro.click();
        Squery.sleepSeconds(5);
        inputPassword.click();
        inputPassword.clear();
        inputPassword.sendKeys(number);
        btnRegistro2.click();
    String imageUrl=captcha.getAttribute("src");

         System.out.println("imagen " + imageUrl);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El principal objetivo de un captcha es precisamente el de no poder automatizarse, evitar que robots puedan acceder a ciertos recursos.

Si el captcha es alphanumerico y no tiene mucha complejidad hay ciertas librerias en python que reconocen esos caracteres si les pasas la imagen y pueden darte el captcha correcto.

Pero si son captchas complejos, lo unico que te queda es que en entornos no productivos ese captcha se desactive y solamente este activo en el entorno de produccion para que tus pruebas automatizadas puedan pasar de ese punto donde se encuentra el captcha.